# Create a table in excel sheet and add rows in table with SQL in loop

Tags: sql, excel, vba

In excel vba ,I am running SQL in a for loop and I want the result of SQL in loop to be added as a table in my excel worksheet.
the example code snippet is given below. So the below code just checks user activity between 2 dates. I need this data to be presented in form of table with excel vba.

```
    Sub activity_count

    Dim x as date
    Dim start_date as date
    Dim End_date as date
    Dim rsResult as object
    Dim strSql as string

    for x=start_date to end_date

    Set rsResult =CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    strSQL="select logdate, username, activity_count from table where logdate='"&start_date
    strSQL= strSQL & "'"
    strSQL=strSQL & ";"

    Call Logon
    rsResult.Open strSQL, Conn

    'with your help ,I need the code to write this data in same excel sheet in the form of table.

    rsResult.close
    Set rsResult=nothing
    Set Conn=nothing
    strSQL=""

    start_date=DateAdd("d",1,start_date)

    next
end sub
```

Comment: What is the data type of the logdate field and which database are you using Microsoft SQL Server, Access, MySQL, Oracle ? How is the start and end date being set ? If I know those I can test an answer before posting.

Comment: I am using teradata. Logdate is also date format. I have only shared a small part of my code. Start and end dates are coming from a cell and are working fine. Consider the routine as activity_count(start_date as date,end_date as date),  I just need the code for copying the result  of sql within the loop to excel sheet. Each loop will create a single row. The final resultset should look like a table. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need a loop if you use WHERE logdate BETWEEN start_date AND end_date ?

Comment: I am working on a project which will let the user enter Start_date and end_date in sheet and a report will be created. The report consists of multiple other things. This is just one part of the report where one sheet will be populated with user activity. You can consider this an example. Based on its solution i will implement actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is part of a bigger report routine, create the db connection at the start of the script, pass it as a parameter to all other parts that need it then disconnect at the end. Not sure why you want to retrieve the records one date at a time when the BETWEEN function does it in one statement. For example

```vb
    Option Explicit
    Sub bigreport()

       Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
       Call Logon  ' establish the connection conn

       ' create activity table
       ' db connection, start_date, end_date , results sheet, table position
       Call activity_count(conn, "01/01/2020", "01/02/2020", "Sheet3", "B2")

       conn.Close
       Set conn = Nothing

    End Sub

    Sub activity_count(conn As ADODB.Connection, start_date As Date, end_date As Date, _
                        sheet_name As String, table_posn As String)

        Dim cmd As ADODB.Command, strSQL As String

        ' query
        strSQL = " SELECT logdate, username, activity_count " & _
                 " FROM Table_1 " & _
                 " WHERE logdate BETWEEN ? AND ? " & _
                 " ORDER BY logdate, username "

        ' parameters
        Dim p1 As String, p2 As String
        p1 = Format(start_date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        p2 = Format(end_date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        'Debug.Print p1, p2

        Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
        With cmd
            .ActiveConnection = conn
            .CommandText = strSQL
            .CommandType = 1 'adCmdText
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P1", adVArChar, 1, 10, p1) '
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P2", adVArChar, 1, 10, p2) ' adParamInput = 1
        End With

        'run query
        Dim rsResult As ADODB.Recordset
        Set rsResult = cmd.Execute

        ' create table
        Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(sheet_name)
        ws.Cells.Clear
        With ws.Range(table_posn)
            .Value = Array("Log Date", "User Name", "Activity Count")
            .Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rsResult
            ws.ListObjects.Add xlSrcRange, .CurrentRegion, , xlYes
            .AutoFilter
            .EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Offset(0, 2).EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With

        ' end
        MsgBox rsResult.RecordCount & " records written to " & sheet_name, vbInformation, "Finished"
        rsResult.Close
        Set rsResult = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the above solution. I understand the “between” clause and its working in Teradata. I asked the original question to understand how to run sql within a loop and show the result in a table format in excel. Using this i want to do something similar where between clause cannot be used.

Comment: @nofel OK I understand, do you want me to update my answer to show for example rows on start_date, start_date +2, start_date+4 etc up to end date ?